Phrase request for the expression 'In the land of the blind, the one-eyed man is king'
A famous Hindi proverb is In the land of the blind, the one-eyed man is king, it roughly describes mediocrity. Basically, the audience is incompetent (hence blind) and speaker is barely competent/mediocre (one-eyed).
Are there any phrases/words/proverbs conveying the same idea?

It is similar in English. It is a quote by Desiderius Erasmus:

Ref. Cambridge dictionary
in the country of the blind, the one-eyed man is king.
idiom UK saying.
said about a difficult situation in which someone with only a few skills is in a better position and more successful than those people who have none.

More Explanation.
What does this mean? An average player in a poor team would be the greatest player on that team.
A person with ordinary intelligence among a gathering of idiots is a genius in contrast.
The point is that you don't necessarily need to be exceptional to succeed. If the competition is poor enough, a mediocre person can win.

The fact that same proverb exists in two different languages, is that supposed to mean something?

Either two cultures came up with the same idea, or the idea spread across the world a very long time ago!

@KateBunting in your opinion, are we getting smarter with time or getting worse? People in 1776 were writing bill of rights (I am sure without electricity and air-conditioning), and in 2024 people are doing rage-bait.

Such opinions are not  relevant to English Language Learners!

@Eric Sayings conveying the same meaning in other Indian languages.
Marathi: A lame cow is the boss among calves. Tamil: In the land of naked, one who wears a loin cloth is the king.
